# Python - Dividing a book in PDF form into individual text files that correspond with page numbers

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I've converted my PDF file into a long string using PDFminer.

I'm wondering how I should go about dividing this string into smaller, individual strings/pages. Each page is divided by a certain series of characters (CRLF, FF, page number etc), and the string should be split and appended to a new text file according to these characters occurring.

I have no experience with regex, but is using the **re** module the best way to go about this?

My vague idea for implementation is that I have to iterate through the file using the re.search function, creating text files with each new form feed found. The only code I have is PDF > text conversion. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**: I think the expression I should use is something like `^.*(?=(\d\n\n\d\n\n\f\bFavela\b))` (capture everything before 2 digits, the line breaks and the book's title 'Favela' which appears on top of each page.

Can I save these `\d` digits as variables? I want to use them as file names, as I iterate through the book and scoop up the portions of text divided by each appearance of `\f\Favela`.

I'm thinking the `re.sub` method would do it, looping through and replacing with an empty string as I go.

Comment: Make an example with some text on a page boundary, and show what you've tried.

Comment: Why do this after the facts? Why not "mining" the text per page to begin with so you don't have to look for page boundaries in the mined text?

Comment: @PeterWood I've included an expression above.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche PDF manipulation is difficult and I don't know enough about it. Working with plaintext seemed like a better way to go about it

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfsplit might be more useful to you, because you could split the PDF into multiple pages and then use each page separately after converting to text